# Policy Gradient Methods when using a fixed initial sequence of actions

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, policy-gradients, off-policy-methods

I am implementing a Policy Gradient agent based on IMPALA. Specifically, I'm working on DeepNash, but that is not considerably different from vanilla IMPALA for the purposes of this question.

In my implementation, I am running vectorized games that I can run batched on my GPU using convolutions and such, similar to this https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-to-play-snake-at-1-million-fps-4aae8d36d2f1?gi=7ef24f81a7a6

However, because of a technical limitation, I have to fix the first $n$ actions of every environment in the batch to be the same. To explain further, these initial $n$ actions consist of placing 'walls', and the placement of walls determines a set of 'vision' mask tensors that filter the observations of the environment. It is not possible to store a separate set of vision masks for each environment, so I've opted to use the same walls/masks for each environment in the batch.

This would be a fine compromise, if not for the fact that it is seems to be off policy, since we are not actually sampling the net works output during this initial stage. In fact, it could be described as selecting from a policy that is identical to the nets except in the initial stage, where it is deterministic. From this viewpoint, it seems natural to use off-policy correction. Indeed, DeepNash already uses IMPALA, so I was hopeful that v-trace would 'absorb' this compromise. However, the policy that is generating the trajectories is deterministic, so this causes singularities in the $\log \frac{\pi (a)}{\mu (a)}$ terms of the v-trace estimate ($\mu$ is the actor policy).

My intuition tells me that it wouldn't be catastrophic if I were to use the trajectories in the batch as if they were on-policy. It seems tantamount to a difference in learning rate at 2 distinct phases of the game: initial and non-initial. Is this correct? Any advice?